# SQL many tables with same column(s) - export to separate table and JOIN on each query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, data-structures, database-design

I'm designing quite a large application that will probably have around 50-100 Tables in general.

I find that almost every table could use a 'deleted', 'timestamp', 'user_id', 'workspace' column.

Now wouldn't it be better practice to get rid of all those column and simply create 3 tables with those names that links both to the row_id and table_id of all the other 50-100 tables? Then on each query I just join those tables?

Surely this must be a problem quite common in database design, but I didn't find anything through Google and other resources.

What's the common approach to this? Surely exporting the logic to external tables seems more like a normalised approach, yet performance might perhaps suffer down the line if there is so many JOINS with every query (Since the existing data structure is quite complex, there will be already plenty of joins etc.).

Comment: From my perspective, bear in mind that you will make an application that needs to be maintained, so, it is difficult to tell you what is the best but I would tell you to make it simple and readable. Think in yourself or some other developer in 5 years building queries or searching for bugs...

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing entity-relationship modeling with object modeling.  Database design does not (necessarily) follow the same principles of design as other applications.

Unfortunately, most databases do not directly support inheritance.  Foreign key relationships require an explicit table and keys.

So, the solution is simply to repeat the columns that you expect to be "in every table".  Some databases allow some flexibility -- say by defining a user-defined record type which can contain the common fields.

Whether this is a good thing or not a good thing is rather moot.  It is the way databases are implemented.  You are free to come up with suggestions for existing databases or implement your own database system.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you plan to do with the data.

Do you plan to do a lot of queries using just the data in these columns (deleted flags, all timestamp flags, etc) without looking at the other data contained in a given row?

If most of the queries you are going to be performing will not want to join then this is the better way to store the data and the indexes can be made to give you more value for this external data.

However, if most of the time you will need this data at the same time you are using the data in the table's row then it should be part of the table.

For example it does not make sense to me to include a deleted flag in a joined table -- you want to be able to filter on a column to know if something should be treated as deleted.

On the other had audit information (date created, date modified, date deleted, who delteted, last access etc etc) all seems like the type of data that could be stored in another table.  Often you will want to just look at audit information by itself and not care about the specific row.